# Why does Workbooks.Open close default workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

We are developing an Excel plugin. 
We have found an issue where the VisualBasic code fails when the user runs it immediately after opening excel.

The code obtains a Workbook from a webservice and attempts to insert the sheet from the new workbook into the original workbook.
This will always fail when the user has not interacted with the "default" Workbook.

What I mean by "default" is the workbook that is created when Excel starts, or I press 'CTRl+N'.

The reason for the failure is that the code:

```
 Workbooks.Open (url)
```

shuts the default Workbook. Why should this be?

Only the default workbook is shut. If we had another Workbook open, then the above code would not shut it.

We have tried to work around this issue by storing a reference to the active workbook.

```
Set wkbMyWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks.Open (url)
```

But after Workbooks.Open closes the "default" Workbook, the reference variable still exists and has content.

What am i doing wrong? can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you as to why it happens, but as a workaround idea, does it still happen if you first write something to the worksheet? For example:

```
cells(1,1)="x"
cells(1,1).ClearContents
```

Comment: Thank you. This does indeed work. But I am unable to use this as we can not modify peoples workbooks and worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

Do a save on the active workbook before doing a `Workbooks.Open...`